# error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive] in makefile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, casting, makefile

while compiling following makefile on ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit) encountered with this error:

```
Ana.cxx:21:46: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

in this line:

```
21 : TThread::Printf("Start of Ana %x \n" ,(int)ptr);
```

here is the makefile:

```
ObjSuf        = o
SrcSuf        = cxx
DllSuf        = so
ExeSuf        =
OutPutOpt     = -o 
CXXFLAGS      = -g -Wall -fPIC -DOSF1 
CXX           = g++
CCFLAGS       = -g -Wall -DOSF1 
CC            = gcc
LD            = g++
LDFLAGS       = -g
SOFLAGS       = -shared
ROOTCFLAGS   := $(shell root-config --cflags) -DFILL_ON_FLY 
ROOTLIBS     := $(shell root-config --libs) -lNew -lThread -lMinuit -lPhysics
ROOTGLIBS    := $(shell root-config --glibs)  -lNew -lThread
EVENTO        = BINAEvent.$(ObjSuf) Ana.$(ObjSuf) BINAEventDict.$(ObjSuf)     mwpc_software.o tcpip.o Genbood.o  
EVENTS        = BINAEvent.$(SrcSuf) Ana.$(SrcSuf) BINAEventDict.$(SrcSuf) mwpc_software.c tcpip.c Genbood.c 
EVENTLIB      = $(ROOTGLIBS)
EVENTEXE      = ana
OBJS          = $(EVENTO)
    .SUFFIXES: .$(SrcSuf) .$(ObjSuf) .$(DllSuf)
    .PHONY:    Aclock Hello Tetris
     $(EVENTEXE):     $(OBJS)
         $(LD) $^ $(ROOTLIBS) $(OutPutOpt) $@
         @echo "$@ done"
     clean:
         @rm -f $(OBJS) core *~ *Dic* ana *.o
     .SUFFIXES: .$(SrcSuf)
     BINAEvent.$(ObjSuf): BINAEvent.h
       BINAEventDict.$(SrcSuf): BINAEvent.h BINAEventLinkDef.h
       @echo "Generating dictionary $@..."
       @rootcint -f $@ -c $^
      .$(SrcSuf).$(ObjSuf):
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(ROOTCFLAGS) -c $<
    .c.$(ObjSuf):
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(ROOTCFLAGS) -c $<
```

What is the proper way to cast this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `(unsigned int)ptr` or `(unsigned long)ptr`

Answer (score 4):

The error has nothing to do with the makefile. The bug is in the source, on the line shown by the error.

On your platform, a pointer does not fit in an `int`. If you cast a pointer to an integer, you should probably use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` from `stdint.h` which are guaranteed to be big enough.

I don't know what `TThread::Printf` is, it's not standard. But the usual way to print a pointer address with `printf` is to pass the pointer as `void*` and use the `%p` format specifier. This is likely to be the case with `TThread::Printf` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The type `int`(32bit) is not big enough to hold 64 bit pointer `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with your `Makefile`; it's an error in your C++ source code. Fortunately, you've shown us the line with the error.

The correct way to print a pointer value in C is to use the `%p` specifier, which requires an argument of type `void*`:

```
TThread::Printf("Start of Ana %p\n", (void*)ptr);
```

`ptr` apparently is already of type `void*`, so the cast isn't necessary, but it's needed for other pointer types.

This assumes that `TThread::Printf` works like `printf`; given the name it certainly should, but it's not guarantee.

For C++ I'd normally advise using C++ I/O with the `<<` operator (and for pointers you have to be careful with `char*`, which has an overload treating it as a pointer to a string), but that might not be available in this case.

You can convert a pointer value to an integer type if you really want to, but it's rarely a good idea, and certainly not necessary if you just want to print its value. The types `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>`, are guaranteed to be able to hold a converted `void*` pointer value without loss of information (and will not be defined if no integer type qualifies). `int` is not, and converting a pointer to `int` can easily lose information.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is using "long long" instead of "int"

Comment: That's not really a good idea. It's sub-optimal on the common implementations where `long long` is larger than a pointer. On implementations where `long long` is just as large as a pointer, it's not any better than the already-posted answers of either (`u`)`intptr_t` or `%p`. (And on the rare implementations where `long long` is smaller than a pointer, you haven't fixed the bug, but I'd be surprised if you manage to find such an implementation.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Mgetz It does provide an answer to the question. It's a poor answer, but it meets the SO standards.